# Azure trial version can't create the database

Tags: azure, trial

I'm in twith rouble the trial  version of Azure.
I don t get any trouble by creating the demo website.
However it seems to be impossible to create any Demo database.
I get the message 'adminPassword' cannot be empty 
Impossible to create the database server too.
I specified the server name, user Id, password connexion string.
Is it due to the fact that tal version are not allowed to create an SQL serverinstance?
Thanks
Hugh

Answer (score 0):

I hope you didn't quit yet. I started with Azure today. I was having the same problem as you. I was viewing the dashboard in Chrome. For some reason Chrome was not sending the password in the request. I switched to Internet Explorer, and what do you know, it worked.